# Get Plugin Definition methods using dependency injection

Tags: plugins, dependency-injection

It is my first time defining a custom Plugin Type.
I think that this might be a comming thing in Drupal but I was not able to find any documentation anywhere.

I want to get Plugin definition methods from controller.

I use this code to get plugin definitions:

```
$type = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.task');
$plugin_definitions = $type->getDefinitions();
```

And that gives me an array of all definitions with Plugin id, class and name.

What I want is to get methods from the definition class.

I don't know if I should create a service for every Plugin definition, but that doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Does Drupal Core have any tools to do this?

Hope that you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance and then use a method on the plugin instance, for example to execute the task, if you have such a method in the plugin class:

```
$task = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.task')->createInstance('my_task');

$task->execute();
```

Comment: That was smart, thank you so much. Since I am extending DefaultPluginManager I must copy the createInstance method from PluginManagerBase but that worked just fine.

Comment: DefaultPluginManager extends PluginManagerBase, so your class inherits it from the grandparent automatically.